# Possible motivation of having a minimal main function as in CPython source code?

Tags: python, c

I was recently looking through the [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython) and noticed something rather intriguing:

```
/* Minimal main program -- everything is loaded from the library */

#include "Python.h"
#include "pycore_pylifecycle.h"

#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
int
wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    return Py_Main(argc, argv);
}
#else
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return _Py_UnixMain(argc, argv);
}
#endif
```

The main function just calls a different function as is stated in the comment above

> Minimal main program

And those two functions which were called (`Py_Main` and `_Py_UnixMain`) don't seem to do drastically different or very complex operations either, and they eventually call the same function (`pymain_main`):

```
int
Py_Main(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    _PyMain pymain = _PyMain_INIT;
    pymain.use_bytes_argv = 0;
    pymain.argc = argc;
    pymain.wchar_argv = argv;

    return pymain_main(&pymain);
}
```

---

```
int
_Py_UnixMain(int argc, char **argv)
{
    _PyMain pymain = _PyMain_INIT;
    pymain.use_bytes_argv = 1;
    pymain.argc = argc;
    pymain.bytes_argv = argv;

    return pymain_main(&pymain);
}
```

It appears that those operations could very easily be done in the `main` or `wmain` functions.

My question is if there is a clear benefit of this choice from a design and structure point of view? Why did the developers of CPython, probably, decide to effectively *create a new main function* instead of using the standard one? Does it make maintenance or debugging easier?

[Link to the main](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Programs/python.c)
[Link to Py_Main and _Py_UnixMain](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/main.c)

Comment: The `#ifdef` directive appears to be the motivation.  They wanted to distingush between Windows and other operating systems.

Comment: @RobertHarvey added the called functions to the question as well, they appear to be more alike than they are different, couldn't they just be incorporated into `main` and `wmain`?

Comment: There are still differences.  There only has to be one significant difference to justify a different method.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's entirely correct, but as the answer denoted *"It would not be necessary to offer these functions as their contents could be written in the real main/wmain"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is not just an application, it can also be embedded as a library. A program can only contain one `main` symbol, so CPython must not provide it if it is intended to be usable as a library.

The use of different Main functions in the Python API is motivated by their different argument types, i.e. `wchar` vs `char`. It would not be necessary to offer these functions as their contents could be written in the real main/wmain, but this keeps Python's file with the main() implementation minimal, and thus more maintainable.

```
+-------------+        +-----------+
| Application |  --->  |  Library  |
|   main()    |        | Py_Main() |
+-------------+        +-----------+
```

Comment: An executable can be (but vanishingly rarely is) a shared library. See for example [on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210873/difference-between-dll-and-exe) or [on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449987/building-a-so-that-is-also-an-executable).